# How would I go about using Set or Setty to store unique arrays?

Tags: raku

I am interested in using `Set` to hold arrays as follows:

```
my @v1 = 1, 2, 3;
my @v2 = 1, 2, 3;

my $set Set.new(@v1, @v2);
```

It would be nice for the `Set` to recognize that the two arrays are the same, as observed with the `~~` operator, but `Set` uses the `===` operator to compare most objects.

```
# desired outcome: set([1 2 3])
# actual outcome: set([1 2 3], [1 2 3])
```

I *could* serialize the array before adding it to the `Set`, use the wonderful `Set` magic, then de-serialize. That seems awkward.

I *could* make a `Setty` class that uses `~~` for a comparator. That seems like a great learning, but perhaps the wrong one.

Is there some more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two arrays are not considered identical because they are not value types: i.e., they can change after having been added to the Set:

```
my @a = 1,2,3;
my @b = 1,2,3;
my $s = Set.new(@a,@b);
dd $s;  # Set $s = set([1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3])
@a.push(4);
dd $s;  # Set $s = set([1, 2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3])
```

Identity of objects in Perl 6 is determined by the `.WHICH` method.  For value types, this returns a unique representation of the values.  For reference types like `Array`s, it returns something that uniquely identifies the object, based on type and its object ID.

Currently, identity is implemented using the `ObjAt` class, but the functionality is still a bit in flux.  However, as long as the `.WHICH` method returns something that uniquely describes what *you* think identifies your object, you should be able to create your own `.WHICH` implementation.  For example:

```
role frozen {
    method WHICH() {
        ObjAt.new(self.join("\0")) # something not occurring in values
    }
}
my @a = 1,2,3;
my @b = 1,2,3;
my $s = Set.new(@a but frozen,@b but frozen);
dd $s;  # Set $s = set([1, 2, 3])
```

It is up to you to not mess with `@a` and `@b` after the `Set` has been created, because then you would be violating the contract that you underwrote by saying `but frozen`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: or rather to not mess with the clones of `@a` and `@b` returned by `but` - we'd have to use `does` to 'freeze' the arrays in place

Comment: The `but` only does a shallow clone of the `Array` object: so the contents of the original array are just sitting uncloned in the copy.  So the size of the array should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a [Set](https://docs.raku.org/type/Set) is not really what you are looking for, perhaps [`classify`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/classify) or [`categorize`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/categorize) is.

```
my @v1 = 1, 2, 3;
my @v2 = 1, 2, 3;

my %classified  := classify *.perl, @v1, @v2;
my %categorized := categorize *.perl, @v1, @v2;
```

In this particular case they both result in:

```
my Any %{Any} = "[1, 2, 3]" => $[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

`my Any %{Any}` creates an anonymous hash with [Any](https://docs.raku.org/type/Any) for values, and [Any](https://docs.raku.org/type/Any) for keys.

The difference between the two is [`classify`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/classify) always takes the result as a single value, and [`categorize`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/categorize) always takes the result as a list of values, and distributes them.

Answer (score 1):

Serializing and de-serializing may not be as awkward as you think, given that the `.perl` method will serialize it for you into something that can simply be EVAL'd later.

Assuming you are collecting your arrays in a Array of Arrays, when you add that AoA to a new `Set`, you can pass all the values to `.perl` via a map. At this point you have a set of strings.

Then later you can pass all the set elements to `EVAL` via another map, assign to a variable and get your values back.

```
my @v1 = 1, 2, 3;
my @v2 = 1, 2, 3;

my @vs = @v1, @v2;

my $set = set( @vs.map(*.perl) );

for $set.keys.map(&EVAL) -> @v {
    say @v.^name;         # Array
    say @v.elems;         # 3
    say @v.join(', ');    # 1, 2, 3
}
```

Also, given how useful sets are, there is the above sugar for creating them, rather than the full `Set.new` syntax, ie: `my $set = set( @things );`

Alternatively, you can also coerce a list to a set (provided it's not infinite) with `my $set = @things.Set;`